# Set TextBox as required based upon “selected” value of DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

`DropDownList`:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="DropDownForm" ID="PositionShift" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select" Value="" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="option1" Value="1" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="option2" Value="2" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="option3" Value="3" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="option4" Value="4" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="option5" Value="5" />    
   <asp:ListItem Text="option6" Value="6" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="option7" Value="7" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

`Label`:

```
<asp:Label ID="RequisitionNumberLabel" Text="Requisition Number" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

`TextBox`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="RequisitionNumberTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

So, I want that when any of the options 1, 5 or 6 are selected the `RequisitionNumberTextbox` field should be required with an "*" on its label.

I found some related examples then I was trying with `Jquery` but I can not figure out on my own.

Comment: Wait, you just want people to do this for you? Where are the rest of your specs?

Comment: Hi   Mathemats.. Please provide me your email add.. I need your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add following code in SelectedIndexChanged event in .cs file

```
 protected void PositionShift_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PositionShift.SelectedIndex == 1 || PositionShift.SelectedIndex == 3 || PositionShift.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {
                RequisitionNumberLabel.Text = "*";
            }
            else
            {
                RequisitionNumberLabel.Text = "Requisition Number";
            }
        }
```

Also, set Autopostback property of DropDownList to True.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use AngularJs and set the value of ng-required attribute based on the value of dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Created dropdown's selected index change method. In that write code if option 1,5,6 selected then change label's caption, include Astrix against name. Also add one required field validator which is by default disabled. And when option 1,5,6 selected, make that validator enable.

Hope this will work.